# Función para cortar un string por palabras

Tags: javascript, wordpress

La siguiente función corta un string, solo se debe ingresar el texto, el inicio y final.

La función es la siguiente:

```
 Generator.prototype.splitbywords = function (variable, start, length) {
    var s = variable,
        len = s.length,
        posStart = Math.max(0, start == 0 ? 0 : s.indexOf(' ', start)),
        posEnd = Math.max(0, length > len ? len : s.indexOf(' ', length));
    return s.substr(posStart, posEnd);
};
```

La función funciona bien *casi siempre*, pero no tiene contemplado *algunos* casos y me gustaría que me ayudaran.

Estos son los casos:

---

1. **Si no existe el último espacio**

para el siguiente texto:

> "PayPal, tu entrada al mercado internacional" (cadena de 44
>   caracteres)

No esta retornando nada, para la función:

```
splitbywords("PayPal, tu entrada al mercado internacional",0,40)
```

Y la razón es que **no encuentra el último espacio luego del largo 40**

```
s.indexOf(' ', length)
```

2. **Que no retorne la coma ","**

También deseo que no corte el texto después de una coma, y el problema esta en la misma linea:

```
posEnd = Math.max(0, length > len ? len : s.indexOf(' ', length));
```

ya que estoy consultando por un *espacio* `" "` y no una coma `", "`. Traté de solucionar esto cambiando esta linea por:

```
posEnd = Math.max(0, length >= len ? len : (s.charAt(s.substr(posStart, s.indexOf(' ', length)) - 1) = "," ? s.indexOf(', ', length): s.indexOf(' ', length));
```

Pero sigue retornando la coma y no entiendo que hice mal.

He agregado algunos de prueba:

```
string = "Hola amigos ¿como están?"

splitbywords(string, 0, 10)
Retorna: "Hola amigos"
CORRECTO

splitbywords(string, 0, 20)
Retorna: ""
PROBLEMA ya que espero que retorne todo el texto
```

======================

```
string = "Hola Julio, estoy bien"

splitbywords(string, 0, 10)
Retorna: "Hola Julio,"
PROBLEMA, no quiero que retorne la coma ","

splitbywords(string, 0, 15)
Retorna: "Hola Julio, estoy"
CORRECTO
```

=====================

EDITO2:
**El código queda de así:**

```
function splitbywords(variable, empieza, termina) {
   var s = variable+' ',   // resuelve problema 1
      largo = s.length,
      posStart = Math.max(0, empieza == 0 ? 0 : s.indexOf(' ', empieza)),
      posEnd = Math.max(0, termina > largo ? largo : s.indexOf(' ', termina)),
      cadena = s.substr(posStart, posEnd);
  if (cadena.charAt(cadena.length-1) === ',') {     //resuelve problema 2
      cadena = cadena.substr(0, cadena.length-1);
  }
  return cadena;
}
```

```js
function splitbywords(variable, empieza, termina) {
  var s = variable+' ',
      largo = s.length,
      posStart = Math.max(0, empieza == 0 ? 0 : s.indexOf(' ', empieza)),
      posEnd = Math.max(0, termina > largo ? largo : s.indexOf(' ', termina)),
      cadena = s.substr(posStart, posEnd);
  if (cadena.charAt(cadena.length-1) === ',') {
      cadena = cadena.substr(0, cadena.length-1);
  }
  return cadena;
}

let text1 = "PayPal, tu entrada al mercado internacional";
let text2 = "Hola Julio, estoy bien";

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = splitbywords(text1, 0 , 25);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = splitbywords(text1, 0 , 30);
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = splitbywords(text2, 0 , 8);
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = splitbywords(text2, 0 , 15);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript splitbywords</h1>

<p>Ejemplos:</p>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo. que hace tu funcion? cortar, pa que son la deteccion de espacios ?

Comment: @lois6b Hola lois, busco corta por palabras y no por caracteres. Saludos

Comment: puedes añadir casos de prueba y como debe comportarse tu funcion?? quieres que corte una longitud pero sin que deje una palabra a la mitad?

Comment: En 1 es normal que no encuentre el ultimo espacio en ese ejemplo pues no existe. El indexOf devolvera -1 por lo que el subString sera entre 0 y -1 y por tanto nulo. Lo que tienes que es comprobar si a partir de la posicion 40 hay espacios, si los hay usa el indexOf, en caso contrario posEnd debera ser el maximo

Comment: @Lithorell Exacto, si se cual es problema, pero no he sido capaz de resolverlo

Comment: var resto = s.substr(lenght, len); Ahora compruebas si resto tiene un espacio, en caso afirmativo haz lo que tenias, en caso negativo que retorne el maximo.

Comment: ¿`length` tiene que ser el **largo mínimo** de la cadena a devolver, o **la posición mínima** desde donde terminar?

Comment: length es la posición donde esta la ultima palabra que deseo mostrar

Comment: @Maguz, o sea que es la **posición mínima** hasta donde extraer (y no tiene nada que ver con el largo)... O sea `splitbywords(texto,10,5)` debería dar error... Además, así como con la coma, ¿también con un punto?... ¿y con un signo de interrogación?

Comment: @Maguz Veo que cada uno ha interpretado cosas diferentes de tu pregunta (al menos 4 personas)... ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para aclarar **específicamente** el comportamiento que debería tener la función?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, creo sería más práctico para éste caso usar [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring) en lugar de [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr).

> El método `substring` obtiene una subcadena donde el final (índice) está determinado por el segundo parámetro. Por otro lado, en el método `substr`, el segundo parámetro especifica **la cantidad de caracteres** a tomar desde una posición inicial.

Yo veo que haces cálculos bastante inncesarios. Por ejemplo, en el problema donde el índice para el final supera el tamaño del texto, por defecto, la función `substring` por defecto devuelve desde el inicio, hasta el final del texto. El problema de la coma, puede resolverse solo haciendo un condicional:

```
if (text.chartAt(end - 1) === ',') {
  _end--;
}
```

Menoramos una unidad porque el método `substring` te devuelve desde `X` hasta `N - 1`.

```js
/**
 * Divide un texto dada un inicio y un final.
 * Si el final es una coma, se excluye meno-
 * rando una unidad al final.
 */
function extract (text, start, end) {
  let _end = end;
  if (text.charAt(end - 1) === ',') {
    _end--;
  }
  return text.substring(start, _end);
}

let text1 = "Hola amigos ¿como están?";
let text2 = "Hola Julio, estoy bien";

console.log('Prueba 1: de 0 a 10: ', extract(text1, 0 , 10));
console.log('Prueba 2: de 0 a 20: ', extract(text1, 0 , 20));
console.log('Prueba 3: de 0 a 10: ', extract(text2, 0 , 10));
console.log('Prueba 4: de 0 a 15: ', extract(text2, 0 , 15));
```

También puedes jugar con expresiones regulares para detectar o reemplazar ciertos caracteres como comas, espacios, etc. Queda a tu creatividad.

Comment: No se si el OP queria dejar palabras a la mitad o no ...

Comment: Tienes razón, creo que `extract` sería un mejor nombre (el sufijo "Text" en este caso no creo sea necesario porque el OP usa la función en el prototipo de un objeto que posiblemente trabaje con textos).

Comment: Hola @guzgarcia, Gracias por la respuesta, pero estas cortando caracteres y yo quiero cortar palabras en tu prueba 1 2 y 4, la palabra final esta cortada, y no es lo que espero

Comment: Cuando dices *"cortar"*, ¿estás diciendo básicamente que quieres **desaparecer** esas palabras o que las quieres usar como referencia para saber desde *dónde* empezar a extraer?

Comment: usar como referencia para saber hasta donde empezar a extraer

Comment: @guzgarcia tu respuesta responde el problema 2, y el problema 1 lo resolvi agregando un espacio al final, saludos y gracias

Comment: La prueba #4 esta fallando

Comment: Al que dió voto negativo, la publicación del OP fue actualizada para explayarse más. Yo respondí antes de ésto al entender mal su problema. @Maguz disculpa por no actualizar, debido al trabajo estuve un poco ocupado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/search) para hacer una busqueda utilizando `RegExp`.

- Como al método `search` no se le puede indicar un `offset` (desde donde empezar a buscar, utilizamos `.substr(offset)`, para cortar el `string` y comenzar la busqueda desde dicho punto.
- Debido a que `text.substr(offset).search(re)` devuelve la posición del caracter en la cadena recortada, es necesario sumar el `offset` para corregir la posición devuelta.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
var splitbywords = function (text, startFrom, lengthFrom) {
    var len = text.length,
        re = /[ ,.]/, // Buscamos alguno de los siguientes caracteres
        from = (startFrom <= 0) ? 0 : text.substr(startFrom).search(re) + startFrom + 1,
        to = (lengthFrom >= len) ? len : text.substr(lengthFrom).search(re) + lengthFrom;
  
    // Si no encontramos algún caracter
    if (from === -1) {
      from = 0;
    }
    if (to === (lengthFrom -1)) {
      to = len;
    }
    return text.substr(from, to);
};

var string = "Hola amigos ¿como están?"
console.log('"' + splitbywords(string, 0, 10) + '" === "Hola amigos"');
console.log('"' + splitbywords(string, 0, 20) + '" === "' + string + '"');

string = "Hola Julio, estoy bien";
console.log('"' + splitbywords(string, 0, 10) + '" === "Hola Julio"');
console.log('"' + splitbywords(string, 0, 15) + '" === "Hola Julio, estoy"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo mismo que quieres hacer pero con una expresión regular:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dividir").click(function(){
    Dividir($("#texto").val());
  });
});

function Dividir(cadena){
  var regExIn = /(?!='.*')\b[\w']+\b/g;
  var palabras = cadena.match(regExIn);
  MostrarPalabras(palabras);
}

function MostrarPalabras(palabras){
  var lista = "";
  $.each(palabras,function(i,v){
    lista += "<li>" + v + "</li>"
  });
  $("#lista").html('');
  $("#lista").append(lista);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Palabras</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="texto">
Ejemplo, varias palabras.  Con Reg Ex, separar y buscar todas.
</textarea>
<br/>
<button id="dividir" class="btn btn-primary">Dividir</button>
<br/><br/>
<div class="row">
  <ol id="lista">
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, de todas las respuestas me quedaría con esta por el uso de expresión regulares.